# Is there a way to dynamically change hostname to ip address mapping in linux (without having to restart)?

Tags: linux

In a linux system, I suppose you can configure hostname to IP address mapping in /etc/hosts, but I guess if you change the mapping for a particular hostname, you would have to restart for the change to take effect.

Is there a way to dynamically (without restarting) change the mapping of a hostname to a different IP address?

Comment: Your guess is wrong. You don't have to restart.

Comment: You don't need to restart at all.

Comment: Oh that's funny. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Why is that funny? Why should that require a restart? Linux is not MS-Windows with its famous "You have moved the mouse pointer! Please restart the system for the change to take effect."

Comment: Most of linux tasks are handled by services. You only need to restart services most of the time, unless you are changing kernel

Answer (score 1):

In linux, administrators can specify the order of the source that an application will ask domain name information.

This file is

```
/etc/nsswitch.conf
```

and the default setting for dns is:

```
hosts: files dns
```

so yes you can add your sites in /etc/hosts and your application will follow that order. You dont need to restart and yes you can do it dynamically.

For more info type:

```
man nsswitch.conf
```

although there is a way for your application to bypass this feature. And that is when the application can "ask for dns" through a remote point or if the application havent built to use the operating system gethostbyname/gethostbyaddr system calls.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the IP address in the /etc/hosts.  Most of the time this change will propagate into the NS cache automatically. However, sometimes you just need to flush the name-server cache on your system.  Depending on what you've got running the actual steps may vary. I'll list a few popular ones:

### NSCD

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
```

OR

```
$ sudo service nscd restart
```

OR

```
$ sudo systemctl restart nscd
```

### dnsmasq

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

OR

```
$ sudo service dnsmasq restart
```

OR

```
$ sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq
```

## BIND server dns cache

**unrelated to OP question but in case someone ends up here**

```
$ sudo rndc restart
```

OR

```
$ sudo rndc flushname foo.local
```

Where `foo.local` is the particular hostname you wish to r